# Maneira diferente de percorrer matriz?

Tags: c++

Estou querendo imprimir uma matriz de forma que a ordem fique assim, por exemplo:
**[1][2][3]
[6][5][4]
[7][8][9]**

mas o código que estou fazendo, só exibe desta maneira:
**[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]**

o código que fiz até agora foi este:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nl, nc;
    cin >> nl;
    cin >> nc;

    int m[nl][nc];
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nl;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< nc; j++)
        {
            m[i][j]=cont;
            cont ++;
        }

    }

    for(int i=0; i<nl;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< nc; j++)
        {
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

é importante que a matriz permaneça recebendo sua dimensão de linhas e colunas através do "cin" do usuário. Não sei o que fazer, alguém pra ajudar?

Comment: Cara, tu precisas debugar o teu algoritmo para ver o que está acontecendo... Talvez com um teste dentro do primeiro `for` que defina a ordem de percorrimento do `for` interno...

Comment: É justamente a parte do percorrimento que não consigo implementar uma lógica. Há uma ordem. Ao invés da matriz ser preenchida linearmente, as linhas pares da matriz são invertidas. Já testei modificar o uso do for, mas não consegui nada...

Comment: Se a linha for par, percorre na ordem crescente. Se for impar, percorre decrescente. Tenta implementar isso...

Comment: Em vez de imprimir sempre `m[i][j]`, basta imprimir `m[i][i % 2 == 0 ? j : nc - j - 1]` -  ou seja, se a linha for par (já que a primeira linha é zero, e a linha que deve ser invertida é a 1), segue a ordem "normal", senão pega a partir do final...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples, ao imprimir a matriz, basta variar a ordem de leitura de acordo com o fato da posição da linha na matriz ser par ou ímpar!

Segue abaixo o trecho correto para funcionar (lembre-se que mudei apenas a parte de imprimir a matriz, a de leitura deve estar igual à sua):

```
    for(int i=0; i<nl;i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            for(int j=0; j< nc; j++)
            {
                cout << m[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=nc-1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                cout << m[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Exemplo de entrada e saída usando o [*Online C++ Compiler*](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/) da Programiz:
[image: output]

Comment: Obrigado! Só tive que fazer um pequeno ajuste, pois esse código fazia a matriz começar em 0 e terminar em um número a menos do esperado, porém, você me ajudou bastante! Obrigado, tava perdido mesmo!